# Ionic Clean up build before submit to Apple App Store

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

Is there any process needed to clean up an Ionic app before submitting to the IOS App Store. I have ensured the app.min.css was being used and the JavaScript files are minified.

I am using the following [guide](http://codewithchris.com/submit-your-app-to-the-app-store/) to upload my Ionic app to the App Store.

The guide does mention to [comment out all of the NSLog statements](http://www.cimgf.com/2009/01/24/dropping-nslog-in-release-builds/) but not much else.

Assuming I have gone through the appropriate usability testing, tested on various devices and the app is functioning exactly as I want for launch on the store, is there any other tips to clean the build before submitting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should also remove the console plugin with: cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.console

You could also minify your html.

Make sure that you are also using production api keys for any external APIs you might be using.

Lastly, you should probably catch and save all errors and stack traces on a DB via REST API, that way you can fix new bugs in production a lot easily. Here's a tutorial: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2542-logging-client-side-errors-with-angularjs-and-stacktrace-js.htm

That's it! Submit to the app store and best of luck!